# Referencing href value and comparing to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I have this:

```
var userName = "$('.home').children('.username').attr('href')";
$(".someclass[href*=userName]").parent().parent().addClass("extra-attribute");
```

I want to add "extra-attribute" to a class based on if it contains a match from the href being referenced. Is this set up right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression is a wrapped in as a string (Remove it) for the first one and for the second line you wrapped `userName` as a part of the selector not the value of userName variable.

So Try:

```
var userName = $('.home').children('.username').attr('href');
$(".someclass[href*=" + userName + "]").parent().parent().addClass("extra-attribute");
```

Also note that `.attr('href')` will get you the href of only the first `userName` anchor tag returned by the collection `$('.home').children('.username')`. Instead of doing `.parent().parent()` you can use `closest('parentparentselector')` provided your parent.parent has that selector and not its parent. That would let you change your html structure as well without changing your script in the future.

Comment: Almost, it needed quotation marks. They weren't being added to the last function. It ended up having to look like this: var userName = $('.home').children('.username').attr('href'); var hrefName = "'" + userName + "'"; $(".someclass[href=" + hrefName + "]").parent().parent().addClass("extra-attribute");

Comment: @user3015600 Yes it needs if you have reserved char you can just do `$('.someclass[href*="' + userName + '"]')`

Answer (score 1):

Close, you need string concatenation:

```
$(".someclass[href*=" + userName + "]")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the following sample before going further :D

```
var v = "1 + 1"; alert(v); // shows "1 + 1"
var v = 1 + 1;   alert(v); // shows "2"
```